# Replace symbol in string depending on position

Tags: r, string

In my three strings below I would like to replace the last `|` sign in the string with one `_` sign, leaving the other unchanged. How do I specify to only replace the last?

In:

```
   d__Bacteria|p__Firmicutes|c__Bacilli|o__Staphylococcales|f__Staphylococcaceae|g__Staphylococcus|s__Staphylococcus|argenteus                      797
    d__Bacteria|p__Firmicutes|c__Bacilli|o__Staphylococcales|f__Staphylococcaceae|g__Staphylococcus|s__Staphylococcus|capitis                          0
    d__Bacteria|p__Firmicutes|c__Bacilli|o__Staphylococcales|f__Staphylococcaceae|g__Staphylococcus|s__Staphylococcus|caprae                         428
```

Out:

```
d__Bacteria|p__Firmicutes|c__Bacilli|o__Staphylococcales|f__Staphylococcaceae|g__Staphylococcus|s__Staphylococcus_argenteus                      797
d__Bacteria|p__Firmicutes|c__Bacilli|o__Staphylococcales|f__Staphylococcaceae|g__Staphylococcus|s__Staphylococcus_capitis                          0
d__Bacteria|p__Firmicutes|c__Bacilli|o__Staphylococcales|f__Staphylococcaceae|g__Staphylococcus|s__Staphylococcus_caprae                         428
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `stri_replace_last_fixed` would make this simple.

```
string <- 'd__Bacteria|p__Firmicutes|c__Bacilli|o__Staphylococcales|f__Staphylococcaceae|g__Staphylococcus|s__Staphylococcus|argenteus'
stringi::stri_replace_last_fixed(string, "|", "_")

#[1] "d__Bacteria|p__Firmicutes|c__Bacilli|o__Staphylococcales|f__Staphylococcaceae|g__Staphylococcus|s__Staphylococcus_argenteus"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an `R base` solution with `gsub`and backreference:

```
gsub("\\|(\\w+$)", "_\\1", string)
[1] "d__Bacteria|p__Firmicutes|c__Bacilli|o__Staphylococcales|f__Staphylococcaceae|g__Staphylococcus|s__Staphylococcus_argenteus"
```